# Add to column sql statement does not work

Tags: sql

Im using some sql to expand to table. I would like to add an extra column to the table match and set a default value of "NO".

I cant understand why this is not working however:

```
 ALTER TABLE match ADD addedToStreakTable VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT VALUE "NO";
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: remove "VALUE"    finally it must be:   DEFAULT 'NO';

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `VALUE` word from `DEFAULT`. Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE match ADD addedToStreakTable VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'NO';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes for string literals. (Double quotes are for delimited identifiers.)

```
ALTER TABLE match ADD addedToStreakTable VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'NO';
```